# Getting 403 forbidden error in flask application

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, python-requests

I am running a flask application in AWS fargate. In the app, I call a POST api which internally needs to call a public endpoint to collect some data using requests.get() method.

```
@app.route("/findByPin", methods=["POST"]
def find_by_pin():
    pincode = request.form['pincode']
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    url = [SOME_URL]?pincode=pincode
    requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The error that I am facing is that the API call to the public endpoint is returning 403 status code in response. While if I run the application in my localhost, it works fine.

Since this is an open endpoint, I don't understand why it would return a 403 Forbidden error.

Edit: This is the error message:
`Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.`

Comment: Do you have an error message along with the error code? The 403 error comes from the public endpoint you are calling, maybe they block AWS IPs to prevent trafic overload from bots.

Comment: Maybe the connection out of your country to the endpoint is restricted.

Comment: @MathieuDéfosse: Yeah, that looks like the case. I tried with some other public endpoint and it worked. Now my question is that is there a way we can prevent the request from getting blocked?

Answer (score 0):

The 403 error comes from the public endpoint you are calling, they might be blocking AWS IPs to prevent trafic overload from bots. You can tunnel your request trough a VPN running on a non AWS instance.